# How can I get a fraction with a matrix in the numerator and denominator?

Tags: fractions

[image]

The above fraction is what I would like to achieve

What I have so far is

```
$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}   - \frac{ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}}{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix} }$
```

and it looks like this

[image]

How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: You also get several errors from that input.

Comment: what are the errors?  my code compiles so I didn't notice any errors

Comment: The second `$` causes TeX to leave math mode before your equation is finished. You should put it all the way at the end (after `\end{bmatrix} }`). You may want to instead use `\[...\]` or `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`instead of `$...$` since this looks like a display equation rather than an inline equation.

Comment: wow that fixed my whole problem, and I got the result i want. thank you

Comment: The fixed code compiles normally and has the expected result for me.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking: the wrong output was obviously caused by the misplaced `$`. When placed correctly, the output is as expected.

Comment: yes I know, I corrected the misplaced `$` and got my desired outcome so my question no longer needs an answer

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\Frac[2]{\frac{\addstackgap{#1}}{\addstackgap{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
  \bracketVectorstack{0\\0\\1\\1} -
  \Frac{
    \bracketMatrixstack{0&0&1&1}\bracketVectorstack{1\\1\\1\\1}
  }{
    \bracketMatrixstack{1&1&1&1}\bracketVectorstack{1\\1\\1\\1}
  }
  \bracketVectorstack{1\\1\\1\\1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The smaller size of `\Frac` is also possible, with a small redefinition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\Frac[2]{{%
  \setstackgap{L}{.7\normalbaselineskip}\TABstackMathstyle{\scriptstyle}%
  \frac{\addstackgap{#1}}{\addstackgap{#2}}%
}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
  \bracketVectorstack{0\\0\\1\\1} -
  \Frac{
    \bracketMatrixstack{0&0&1&1}\bracketMatrixstack{1\\1\\1\\1}
  }{
    \bracketMatrixstack{1&1&1&1}\bracketMatrixstack{1\\1\\1\\1}
  }
  \bracketVectorstack{1\\1\\1\\1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `bsmallmatrix` environment, provided by the `mathtools` package, to render the row and column vectors in the `\frac` expression more compactly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}   
- \frac{ 
\begin{bsmallmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 
\end{bsmallmatrix}  
\begin{bsmallmatrix}
  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 
\end{bsmallmatrix}}{%
\begin{bsmallmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 
\end{bsmallmatrix}  
\begin{bsmallmatrix}
  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 
\end{bsmallmatrix} }
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\]
\end{document}
```